# Why is my OR operator not working in my WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I need to write a where statement that only returns names starting with A, B, C, or E. I have a WHERE clause with a less that D condition, and that seems to work fine. But my Equals E condition doesn't appear to be working.

```
SELECT vendor_name,
    CONCAT(vendor_contact_last_name, ', ', vendor_contact_first_name) AS full_name
FROM vendors
WHERE vendor_contact_last_name < 'D' 
    OR vendor_contact_last_name = 'E'
ORDER BY vendor_contact_last_name, vendor_contact_first_name;
```

It is only returning names that start with A, B, and C.

Comment: Please post your query or we cannot help

Comment: Done, I wasn't sure how to at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following using [`LEFT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left):

```
SELECT vendor_name,
    CONCAT(vendor_contact_last_name, ', ', vendor_contact_first_name) AS full_name
FROM vendors
WHERE LEFT(vendor_contact_last_name, 1) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'E')
ORDER BY vendor_contact_last_name, vendor_contact_first_name;
```

... or using [`RLIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
SELECT vendor_name,
    CONCAT(vendor_contact_last_name, ', ', vendor_contact_first_name) AS full_name
FROM vendors
WHERE vendor_contact_last_name RLIKE '^[A-CE]'
ORDER BY vendor_contact_last_name, vendor_contact_first_name;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f00458abf6eb02f2155d6a92704290b)